# When assigning memory dynamically in C for strings, do you count the \0 end of string char?

Tags: c, string, malloc, calloc

When assigning memory dynamically in C for strings, do you count the \0 end of string char?

```
char *copyInto, *copyFrom="test";

// Should 
copyInto = (char*)malloc(strlen(copyFrom));
// suffice?

// or should this be the following?
copyInto = (char*)malloc(strlen(copyFrom)+1);

// assuming you want to copy the string from copyFrom into copyInto
strcpy(copyInto,copyFrom);

// Does anyone recommend just \0-ing the whole copyInto as in
copyInto = (char*)calloc(strlen(copyFrom)+1);
// and if so, should it still be (strlen(copyFrom)+1) size?
```

Comment: Lets see... do you plan to store that null-terminator?

Comment: I read the title and not the body.  Answer is yes.  Allocate length plus 1 chars.

Comment: @K-ballo If I did not store that null-terminator, wouldn't the C stdlib string processing functions not know where the string ended? If the memory byte following the last valid char location were not set to \0 the C string processor would keep going until the first \0.  We can't guarantee that the byte following the last char is \0 if we don't set it and store it ourselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't cast the return values of `malloc()` or `calloc()` (or `realloc()` for that matter) in a C program.
2. Yes, you need to have the `+1`.
3. Why bother using `calloc()` to zero out the whole string if you're just going to copy into it immediately?  Seems like a waste of cycles to me.

Comment: In re: #1, add something like `#include <stdlib.h>` instead which will prevent the compiler throwing those annoying warnings

Comment: I agree about calloc(). I converted a whole Windows Borland C++ Builder application from calloc to malloc and it cut down on a lot of extra processing and time. Also, I put common lib files in a pre-compiled header and this saved a lot of compile time. When I added #include <stdlib.h> to my precompiled header file and nixed the explicit (char*) cast, I got an error "[C++ Error] formName.cpp(770): E2034 Cannot convert 'void *' to 'char *'"

Comment: Is the absence of explicit (char*) casting to a malloc() pointer output only a warning in C but an error in C++?

Comment: It's not even a warning in C.  The cast is required in C++.